# Cosmos DB Emulator on Virtual Machine

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I installed Cosmos DB Emulator on a virtual machine. The default access url is localhost:[Port number].

Is there any way to connect to the emulator from my development machine.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. It requires that the emulator is started with network access, you might also need to register the SSL certificates in the client machine.

You can find the details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-the-emulator-on-a-local-network